# So confused about 32-bit vs 64-bit, please help

Tags: 18.04, 64-bit, 32-bit

I am running (Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS) on a laptop with an Intel Corei7 processor:

```
$ lscpu

    Architecture:        i686
    CPU op-mode(s):      32-bit, 64-bit
    Byte Order:          Little Endian
    CPU(s):              8
    On-line CPU(s) list: 0-7
    Thread(s) per core:  2
    Core(s) per socket:  4
    Socket(s):           1
    Vendor ID:           GenuineIntel
    CPU family:          6
    Model:               60
    Model name:          Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4710HQ CPU @ 2.50GHz
```

---

I am trying to run the following:

```
$ file electrum-ltc-3.3.5.1-x86_64.AppImage

electrum-ltc-3.3.5.1-x86_64.AppImage: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib, for GNU/Linux 2.6.18, stripped
```

---

But I keep getting:

```
$ ./electrum-ltc-3.3.5.1-x86_64.AppImage 

bash: ./electrum-ltc-3.3.5.1-x86_64.AppImage: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

---

I am so confused about i686 vs x86_64, but from what I've read, my pea brain suspects that the "Architecture: i686" is clashing with "ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64". Can someone please give me some guidance here. I just want to run the stupid electrum-ltc app. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have a 32-bit Ubuntu running. Please see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/77718/32-bit-64-bit-cpu-op-mode-on-linux

Comment: Thank you for such a quick response. I'll reinstall using the amd64 version.

Answer (score 0):

64 bit computers can run 32 bit executables, but 32 bit computers cannot run 64 bit executables.  Even if your computer is 64 bit capable, if you're running a 32 bit operating system, you'll be unable to run 64 bit executables.